# Having issues with SQLite DB executing within a Perl script

Tags: linux, perl, sqlite

So I'm new to Perl along with being new to SQLite. I have SQL experience, but this new Perl syntax is throwing me a bit.

So I have an issue where I'm trying to create a DB from a IPtable log using a Perl script to parse the data that the table has and send notifications out to people.  The script also sends notifications to the users, but I don't believe that has anything to do with this problem.

This is the error I'm receiving.

> DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: no such table: syslog_decom_notif at ./send_notification_syslog.pl line 251.
>   Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at ./send_notification_syslog.pl line 252.

Below is the code where I'm receiving the error from:

```
2 sub select_contacts {
233         my @contact_info;
234         my $dbh = DBI->connect( DECOM_NOTIFICATION_DB ,"","");
235
236         my ( $where_clause, @exec_params ) = build_where_clause();
237
238         my $SQL = <<SQL;
239 select
240                 contact
241         ,       status
242         ,       contact_mngr
243         ,       hostname
244         ,       contact_type
245         ,       syslog_server
246 from
247         syslog_decom_notif
248 $where_clause
249 SQL
250         debug  ( __LINE__ . " Excuting SQL = \n[ $SQL ]\n" );
251         my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $SQL );
252         $sth->execute( @exec_params );
253         if ( $debug_mode ) {
254                 my @cols = @{$sth->{NAME}};
255                 print join '|', @cols;
256                 print "\n";
257         }
258         while (my @res = $sth->fetchrow) {
259                 for ( my $i=0; $i<@res; $i++ ) { $res[$i] = 'Null' if ! defined $res[$i]; }
260                 my $row = join '|', @res;
261                 debug "$row\n";
262                 push @contact_info, $row;
263         }
264         $sth->finish();
265         return @contact_info;
266 }
```

I've searched around and I can't seem to find anything that could really help with this problem.

I appreciate any and all ideas.

Best Regards

Comment: It says `no such table: syslog_decom_notif`. Is there such a table? Try executing the query (`$SQL`, you're already outputting it) in a command line db client. Also it says you're creating a table and storing data, but your code only shows a `SELECT` statement. That's a bit odd. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for you input! I edited my post, I meant to say that the data is parsed in the DB and then notifications through email are sent out.  I didn't mean to say the data is parsed then stored.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Well the simple truth is that, as it says, DBI cannot find a table called `syslog_decom_notif` in the database you have opened. After the `prepare` has failed nothing else is going to work.

I presume you have the table name correct, so I wonder about the value of `DECOM_NOTIFICATION_DB`. Where has this come from? Is it perhaps a string defined with `use constant`?

In the `connect` call for SQLite, DBI expects a DSN that looks like `dbi:SQLite:dbname=my_db_file`. If the file doesn't exist it will be created, so perhaps you have this set up wrongly and you are working with an empty database?

---

**Update**

To see what is in the database you have connected to, add this right after the `DBI->connect` call. It will print a list of tables in the connected database. Make sure the `END` terminator appears at the start of the line and has no whitespace before or after it.

```
my $tables = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref(<<END);
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table'
ORDER BY name
END

print "$_\n" for @$tables;
```

Comment: The DECOM_NOTIFICATION_DB is set as a use constant early in the script.
As for the connect you are speaking of, I'm still looking into it, but I'll get back to you.

Comment: I have added to my answer to show some code that will list the tables in the SQLite database you have connected to.

Comment: I found out the error.  It was the use of a constant somewhere was a redundant when a package was inserted into the code.  I thank you for the help!